# Menu in android, application doesn't launch

Tags: android, menu, crash

i'm trying to make a simple app for android concerning menus, but the application crashes when i launch it and the program closes.
here's the code ->

**This is my xml file:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.testemenu.MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Salut !"    
/>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item1">
    </item>
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item2" 
            android:title="Item2">
        </item>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:title="Item3">
        </item>
    </menu>
</menu>
```

**This is my JAVA file:**

```
package com.example.testemenu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }
     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         MenuInflater inflateur = getMenuInflater();
         inflateur.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
         return true;
     }
}
```

I've tried to compile it and run it many times and the problem still exist, i just started studing menus in android, i hope you guys could help me, thanks in advance :D

Comment: logcat information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that application doesn't start because xml file with menu items is incorect. If you want to create nested menus, xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:title="Item1">
    </item>
    <!-- use "group" tag insted of another "menu"-->
    <group android:id="@+id/group>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item2" 
            android:title="Item2">
        </item>
        <item 
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:title="Item3">
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#groups) is more info about menu groups.

Comment: Thanks :D , it was right, not correct to add a menu under another one without an item as an intermediate item (y) :D

Answer (score 0):

Hey you didn't show us your log so I will post simple autogenerated Activity with OptionsMenu (with appcompat):

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="hey"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

menu_main.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.example.antonkazakov.stackhelp.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

So if you are using up-to-date Android studio it will auto generate menu when creating activity.